# codeigniter session data is lost after jquery redirect

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am struggling with this code for over 12 hours now, and any help will be deeply appreciated. Few words before i post the code. I have very similar code for the back office authentication, and now i am working on site members authentication. Back office works fine, front end does not.

It is CodeIgniter application and is something that I have done numerous times. If the back end code didn't worked, i would suspect that server have different settings, but the back end code works. I am not beginner with ci, and I guess that i have done some stupid mistake somewhere...

Here is the login function:

```
public function loginCheck()
    {     
        // set the validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('memberusername', 'Username', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('memberpassword', 'Password', 'required|trim|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><p class=jsdiserr>', '</p><br />');
        // if validation is passed

        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {


            $this->db->where('memberUserName', $this->input->post('memberusername'));
            $this->db->where('memberOldPassword', strtoupper(md5("EBOSS/".$this->input->post('memberpassword')."/EBOSS")));
            $query = $this->membersModel->get();
            if($query)
            {

                $data = array(
                    'memberID'                      => $query[0]['memberID'],
                    'memberUserName'                => $query[0]['memberUserName'],
                    'memberOldPassword'             => $query[0]['memberOldPassword'],
                    'memberEmail'                   => $query[0]['memberEmail'],
                    'isUserLoggedIn' => TRUE
                );           
                $currentUser = array();
                //echo "Here after the data?";
                //die();
               $this->session->set_userdata('currentMember', $data);
                $currentMember = $this->session->userdata('currentMember');
               // print_r($currentMember);
                //die();

                echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
        } else {   
                echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong credentials"));
        }
        //  form validation has failed 
        } else {     
            $errorMessage = "Wrong Username or passwrod!";
        }
    }   // end of function loginCheck
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
// user fill both fields, user name and memberpassword, so form can be submitted
   jQuery("#formLogin").submit(function(e){     
       e.preventDefault();

        var memberusername = jQuery(this).find("#memberusername").val();
        var memberpassword = jQuery(this).find("#memberpassword").val();
        var obj = {memberusername: memberusername, memberpassword: memberpassword};
        var url = jQuery(this).attr("action");
        jQuery.post(url, obj, function(r){
            if(r.success) window.location.replace('http://www.example.net/memberAccount/memberDashboard'); 
            else  jQuery('#errorMessageTop').fadeIn();
        }, 'json')
   })
```

I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null

On the end, here is the output on the user account page:

```
Array
(
[session_id] => 711a8349fe7414802928ac27b7bd2c4f
[ip_address] => 62.103.42.2
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
[last_activity] => 1416509476
[currentUser] => Array
    (
        [authbackofficeuserID] => 428
        [authbackofficeuserUserName] => mysuername
        [authbackofficeuserPassword] => 69e3184e2cdc3605693ba24887c519aaafc89477
        [authbackofficeuserEmail] => me@mail.com
        [authbackofficeuserFirstName] => My
        [authbackofficeuserLastName] => Name
        [isUserLoggedIn] => 1
    )

)
```

current user is the data of the user that is logged in in the back office, but the currentMember that should be here is nowhere to be found.

Things to be more strange, if i comment out the javascript, the data is shown here in the array output. As soon as I remove the comment, and i log out, when I try to login again, that data (currentMember) is gone.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: How are you keeping track of the CI session?  Database or cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed **$query->result_array();**

```
$members = $query->result_array();

if(count($members) != 0){
 //set your session logic here
}
```

Remember use the MVC; i see you are mixing *$this->db* functions (Model) and *$this->form_validation* function (Controller)

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) {
        $this->db->where('memberUserName', $this->input->post('memberusername'));
        $this->db->where('memberOldPassword', strtoupper(md5("EBOSS/".$this->input->post('memberpassword')."/EBOSS")));
        $query = $this->membersModel->get();
        $members = $query->result_array();

        if(count($members) != 0){
            $data = array(
                'memberID'                      => $members[0]['memberID'],
                'memberUserName'                => $members[0]['memberUserName'],
                'memberOldPassword'             => $members[0]['memberOldPassword'],
                'memberEmail'                   => $members[0]['memberEmail'],
                'isUserLoggedIn' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('currentMember', $data);
            echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
        }else {
            echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong credentials"));
        }

} else {     
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Incorrect inputs"));
}
```

And check your **memberDashboard** controller for session

Comment: I found that i have altered the javascript...if(true) window.location.replace('http://www.example.net/memberAccount/memberDashboard'); and that cause any user name and password to be true. line is now if(r.success) window.location.replace('http://www.example.net/memberAccount/memberDashboard'); and now i am getting the following error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null

Comment: i will now edit the question...if you have any idea, just post it. I am over14 hours over this...and i will be here until i solve it.